# UIPickerView reloadData

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'm changing components (in particular, the number and color of components), in a UIPickerView that I call pickerOne, so after making the changes, I call:

```
[pickerOne reloadData];
```

and it appears to be working perfectly however, I'm getting a compile warning:

```
warning: 'UIPickerView' may not respond to '-reloadData'
```

Although this appears to work, is there something else that I should use to reload data?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the confusion stemmed from UITableView which has reloadData but UIPickerView doesn't (as per others' answers below).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you should be using:

reloadComponent:

or

reloadAllComponents:

Comment: yup, no ugly warning across my code and works just as well.  thank you very much

Comment: Just a note - reloadAllComponents does not accept an argument. So it should probably read: reloadAllComponents instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should be calling `reloadComponent:` or `reloadAllComponents:`.

There may be a private `reloadData` used under the covers, but it's not part of the public API, and therefore, shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: 2 identical answers within 3 minutes, I guess I should have known this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using: `reloadComponent` or `reloadAllComponents`.

But these methods are useless unless you connect `UIPickerViewDalegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` to file owner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question has already been answered with the same information you have written here. If you want to add something to their answers, you can put it in a comment under it. :)