# Set up a pickerView from a asynchronous Json array

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I've a function, getSemainesStages() which read a distant json file and put the result in a (global scope) array.

The problem is that it's asynchronous like somebody explain to me and I need this array to populate a pickerView datasource.

So when I call:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return lesSemaines.count
    }
```

The array is still empty, and the same for

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return lesSemaines[row]
    }
```

How can I do that only after my getSemainesStages() function is empty ?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions [for one topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184215/json-and-variable-scope) and [search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206956/1457385) before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `UIPickerView.reloadAllComponents()` after the array has been populated to reload the sections/rows:

```
var lesSemaines: [String] {
    didSet { 
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```